# Excel Vertical and Horizontal view of cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a booking system using Excel. I know this may not be the best option, however so far this is what I have come up with:

- sheet1 with all customer details
- sheet2 with all booking details

The customer id and name are ref to sheet2 so I don't have to type them again.

On sheet2 I have the customer name in column A and in Column B dates for different days laid out horizontally.

For example:

```
Customer Name             Course 1       Course2      Course3
John Smith                01.01.2014     02.01.2014   03.01.2014
Bob Green                 02.01.2014     03.01.2014   04.01.2014
```

The problem I am having at the moment is not being able to identify all customers who are booked on same date. For example if I want to see all the customers who are booked for 01.01.2014, how is that possible?

Any help will be great, or if you have better ideas about creating a booking systems suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, but please reconsider this approach.  Building an "application" in Excel will cause you all kinds of trouble in the long run.

Comment: To be more helpful to you, what programming skills do you have? e.g. if you are familiar with VB(A) then maybe a small VB/.Net application would be easy to pull off yet provide a much better user experience and be much easier to maintain, extend, get collaboration on, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do have very basic VB(A) skills and was considering to create a user forum, could you recommend me some website/ tutorials to follow? I just need help to start after that I can carry on..

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your layout, then you can apply a filter.  A better layout would be:

```
Customer Name  Course Name  Date
John Smith     Course 1     01.01.2014
John Smith     Course 2     02.01.2014
John Smith     Course 3     03.01.2014
Bob Green      Course 1     02.01.2014
Bob Green      Course 2     03.01.2014
Bob Green      Course 3     04.01.2014
```

Then just apply a filter on the Date column.  To see all people in the same course and on the same date, apply a filter to both the Course Name and Date columns.

Comment: Thank you, yes this will be my last option if nothing else works.

Comment: This should be your first step, not your last option, in my opinion. [Normalizing your data](http://www.excelcampus.com/modeling/structure-pivot-table-source-data/) like this will also allow you to use pivot tables, and perhaps avoid the whole VBA ordeal. If you want to normalize existing data [this code I wrote](http://yoursumbuddy.com/data-normalizer/) could be helpful.